# Laravel cannot find self defined service providers

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, composer-php, service-provider

I'm using Laravel for my project, I created a service provider and it's located in `app/services/ToolboxServiceProvider.php`, and I added

```
'providers' => array(
    ....
    'services\ToolboxServiceProvider',
);
```

in my app.php config file. Now when loading the app, it says the service provider cannot find, I know that something's wrong with my path setting in that providers array, question is: how to make it right? Thanks in advance.

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.2.*"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
},
"minimum-stability": "stable"
```

}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should add into  `autoload` => `classmap` section of your `composer.json`:

```
"app/services",
```

so it should look like:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php",
        "app/services",
    ]
},
```

In your provider file, at the beginning you should have:

```
<?php namespace services;
```

(in lower case).

And after those changes you should run:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

to rebuild classmap

Comment: Yeah, that did the trick, and yours is the most complete answer, right on, thank you sir! But another question, how to inject this service provider into my controller?
public function __contruct(ToolboxServiceProvider $toolbox) doesn't seem right...

Comment: @dulan I haven't used injecting providers into controllers. In the above you used `__contruct` and not `__construct` - maybe that's the problem? If not, you should create another question describing in details your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Create the service provider using something like this in `app/services` folder, notice the `namespace`:

```
<?php

namespace Services;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ToolboxServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    //...
}
```

Then in the `providers` array add `'Services\ToolboxServiceProvider'`. Then add `"app/services"` in the `classmap` section in `composer.json` file and dump the autoloader.

Comment: Did as you told, also because I created the 'services' folder manually, I noticed that in composer.json under "autoload" there is no 'app/services', added that manually again, now the app loads. But here comes another question: how to inject this service provider in my controller?

Comment: public function __construct(ToolboxServiceProvider $toolboxServiceProvider) { ... } doesn't work, but use Services\ToolboxServiceProvider does. Thanks.

Comment: To use the service provider in the controller, you need use `use Services\ToolboxServiceProvider` then use it directly ot inject it in the constructor using `public function __construct(ToolboxServiceProvider $toolboxServiceProvider) { ... }`, the use of `use` is required.

Comment: Figured out where the problem is, since I'm using namespace Services, when injecting that class into my construct function, I should use namespace as well:
public function __construct(Services\ToolboxServiceProvider $toolbox)
Thanks man!

Answer (score -1):

What namespace is ToolboxServiceProvider using? Have you added autoloading in the composer.json file? Have you tried a `composer dump-autoload?`

Comment: namespace services;
I did php artisan compose dump-autoload and php artisan dump-autoload, no luck, gives me some cannot find error.

Comment: Right, it's actually composer dump-autoload.

Comment: Can you share your composer.json file as well as the error you are receiving?

Comment: Just updated my composer.json file, run composer dump-autoload, no error pops out, but the app still says:
Class 'services\ToolboxServiceProvider' not found

Comment: The contents of your answer should have been presented as a comment.